# Wordpress HTML/CSS not displaying correctly - no changes made

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having trouble identifying a problem and it is driving me crazy.  If this is a poor question or in the wrong place please have mercy, I am exhausted trying to figure this out.

Here is how my website is displaying: [My Site](http://quillenbrosinc.com/)

And here is how it is supposed to look:
[Archive of Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916145943/http://www.quillenbrosinc.com/)

Nothing has changed as far as I can tell.  I have disabled plugins, re-uploaded them there.  My mind is boggled!?  It looks the same (code) but appears different.  What am I missing!?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to get this as well, what you should do is to redownload the layout, thats what solved my issue. I remember adding 1 line to css and removing it, the layout got stuck and refused to update, so that was my solution. I hope someone else can give you a better one though :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with jQuery in your website.
I think you need to update your theme.
your theme is from 6/2014 and now is 6/2016...

Your js makes all this section on home vertical align to middle. And the js doesn't work now and stay on top.

Update your theme :)